# Google Maps API - What's showing?

Tags: google-maps, plot

How do we know programatically what portion of the map is visible at any given time? For example:

When I load a map I set the center so I know which point I am on and will know what properties to load. However, when a user drags the map along or zooms into a smaller section of the map. How do I know which properties to plot at that point? How will know what exactly the user is looking at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `bounds = map.getBounds()` (assuming that `map` is the variable where you store the Google map) and this will return the bounds of the current viewport.

Then, with `bounds.getSouthWest()` and `bounds.getNorthEast()` you will obtain the Latitude and Longitude of both corners so you have all you need to know what the user is seeing.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's exactly what I was trying to figure out.